# Grouping fails when nesting data. How can I group this result by Unit?

Tags: sql-server

How can I group this result by UnitMisnumber ?

Please see attached images of Data, Desired result and Current status.
I have hard time to use pivot and partition over, so I tested join and group, but I don't get desired result. Can anyone point me in the right direction?  Below are the pictures of Data, Goal and Current Status.

Units are for selfdriving cars and they contain 2 cameras positioned Left and Right with an identifying number. Instead of Left on one row and right on next row, the goal is to show Left and Right as columns grouped by Unit.

```
Select #result.UnitMISNumber, t.CameraMISNumber [Left], x.CameraMISNumber [Right] from #result
left join (Select * from #result where Position = 'Left') t on t.CameraObjectID = #result.CameraObjectID
left join (Select * from #result where Position = 'Right') x on x.CameraObjectID = #result.CameraObjectID group by  #result.UnitMISNumber, t.CameraMISNumber, x.CameraMISNumber
```

[Data]

```
+------------------------+----------------------+-------------------------+----------------------------------+------------------------+----------+---------------+
|     UnitMISNumber      | CustomerSerialNumber | CameraTimestampCOTFT4A  |        CameraSerialNumber        |    CameraMISNumber     | Position | ProductNumber |
+------------------------+----------------------+-------------------------+----------------------------------+------------------------+----------+---------------+
| 6809930002020463005102 | 87501VC0002101040010 | 2020-11-1316:06:31.777  | 568802A020888D9A430BCC400000000  | 6465902002020372004505 | Left     | 680993000H    |
| 6809930002020463005102 | 87501VC0002101040010 | 2020-11-13 08:46:20.187 | 9ACDE222016B15A460227CA00000000  | 6465902002020372007710 | Right    | 680993000H    |
| 6809930002020477000101 | 87501VC0002101040040 | 2020-11-1719:04:41.730  | B40C0132D01E1E4662745E800000000  | 6465902002020454010709 | Left     | 680993000H    |
| 6809930002020477000101 | 87501VC0002101040040 | 2020-11-1811:33:54.533  | 064C4E8A66877204E251E69400000000 | 6465902002020454014407 | Right    | 680993000H    |
| 6809930002020484000204 | 87501VC0002101040020 | 2020-11-0520:54:47.060  | FB813AEE8D88F3584450CE9400000000 | 6465902002020433006201 | Left     | 680993000H    |
| 6809930002020484000204 | 87501VC0002101040020 | 2020-11-04 21:29:55.123 | 10304003850933B3E632A6EC00000000 | 6465902002020431008907 | Right    | 680993000H    |
+------------------------+----------------------+-------------------------+----------------------------------+------------------------+----------+---------------+
```

[Desired]

```
+------------------------+----------------------+-------------------------+----------------------------------+------------------------+------------+----------------------------------+------------------------+------------+
| 6809930002020463005102 | 87501V60002101040010 | 2020-11-13 16:06:31.777 | 568802A020888D9A430BCC400000000  | 6465902002020372004505 | 680993000H | 9ACDE222016B15A460227CA00000000  | 6465902002020372007710 | 680993000H |
| 6809930002020477000101 | 87501860002101040040 | 2020-11-17 19:04:41.730 | B40C0132D01E1E4662745E800000000  | 6465902002020454010709 | 680993000H | 064C4E8A66877204E251E69400000000 | 6465902002028454014407 | 680993000H |
| 6809930002020484000204 | 87501V60002101040020 | 2020-11-05 20:54:47.060 | FB813AEE8D88F3584450CE9400000000 | 6465902002020433006201 | 680993000H | 103D4003850933B3E632A6EC00000000 | 6465902002020431008907 | 680993000H |
+------------------------+----------------------+-------------------------+----------------------------------+------------------------+------------+----------------------------------+------------------------+------------+
```

Data
[image: 1]

Desired result
[image: 2]

Current status
[image: 3]

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I might approach this.

You can run this example in SSMS:

```
DECLARE @Data table (
    UnitMISNumber varchar(255),
    CustomerSerialNumber varchar(255),
    CameraTimestampCOTFT4A datetime,
    CameraSerialNumber varchar(255),
    CameraMISNumber varchar(255),
    Position varchar(10),
    ProductNumber varchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO @Data (
    UnitMISNumber, CustomerSerialNumber, CameraTimestampCOTFT4A, CameraSerialNumber, CameraMISNumber, Position, ProductNumber
)
VALUES
( '6809930002020463005102', '87501VC0002101040010', '2020-11-13 16:06:31.777', '568802A020888D9A430BCC400000000', '6465902002020372004505', 'Left', '680993000H' ),
( '6809930002020463005102', '87501VC0002101040010', '2020-11-13 08:46:20.187', '9ACDE222016B15A460227CA00000000', '6465902002020372007710', 'Right', '680993000H' ),
( '6809930002020477000101', '87501VC0002101040040', '2020-11-17 19:04:41.730', 'B40C0132D01E1E4662745E800000000', '6465902002020454010709', 'Left', '680993000H' ),
( '6809930002020477000101', '87501VC0002101040040', '2020-11-18 11:33:54.533', '064C4E8A66877204E251E69400000000', '6465902002020454014407', 'Right', '680993000H' ),
( '6809930002020484000204', '87501VC0002101040020', '2020-11-05 20:54:47.060', 'FB813AEE8D88F3584450CE9400000000', '6465902002020433006201', 'Left', '680993000H' ),
( '6809930002020484000204', '87501VC0002101040020', '2020-11-04 21:29:55.123', '10304003850933B3E632A6EC00000000', '6465902002020431008907', 'Right', '680993000H ' );

SELECT
    lft.UnitMISNumber,
    lft.CustomerSerialNumber,
    MAX ( lft.CameraTimestampCOTFT4A ) AS CameraTimestampCOTFT4A,
    lft.CameraSerialNumber AS CameraSerialNumber_Left,
    lft.CameraMISNumber AS CameraMISNumber_Left,
    lft.ProductNumber AS CameraMISNumber_Left,
    rgt.CameraSerialNumber_Right,
    rgt.CameraMISNumber_Right,
    rgt.ProductNumber_Right
FROM @Data AS lft
OUTER APPLY (
    
    SELECT TOP 1
        CameraSerialNumber AS CameraSerialNumber_Right,
        CameraMISNumber AS CameraMISNumber_Right,
        ProductNumber AS ProductNumber_Right
    FROM @Data AS x WHERE 
        x.UnitMISNumber = lft.UnitMISNumber
        AND x.Position = 'Right'

) AS rgt
WHERE
    lft.Position = 'Left'
GROUP BY
    lft.UnitMISNumber, lft.CustomerSerialNumber, lft.CameraSerialNumber, lft.CameraMISNumber, lft.ProductNumber,
    rgt.CameraMISNumber_Right, rgt.CameraSerialNumber_Right, rgt.ProductNumber_Right
ORDER BY
    UnitMISNumber;
```

Returns

```
+------------------------+----------------------+-------------------------+----------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+----------------------------------+------------------------+---------------------+
|     UnitMISNumber      | CustomerSerialNumber | CameraTimestampCOTFT4A  |     CameraSerialNumber_Left      |  CameraMISNumber_Left  | CameraMISNumber_Left |     CameraSerialNumber_Right     | CameraMISNumber_Right  | ProductNumber_Right |
+------------------------+----------------------+-------------------------+----------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+----------------------------------+------------------------+---------------------+
| 6809930002020463005102 | 87501VC0002101040010 | 2020-11-13 16:06:31.777 | 568802A020888D9A430BCC400000000  | 6465902002020372004505 | 680993000H           | 9ACDE222016B15A460227CA00000000  | 6465902002020372007710 | 680993000H          |
| 6809930002020477000101 | 87501VC0002101040040 | 2020-11-17 19:04:41.730 | B40C0132D01E1E4662745E800000000  | 6465902002020454010709 | 680993000H           | 064C4E8A66877204E251E69400000000 | 6465902002020454014407 | 680993000H          |
| 6809930002020484000204 | 87501VC0002101040020 | 2020-11-05 20:54:47.060 | FB813AEE8D88F3584450CE9400000000 | 6465902002020433006201 | 680993000H           | 10304003850933B3E632A6EC00000000 | 6465902002020431008907 | 680993000H          |
+------------------------+----------------------+-------------------------+----------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+----------------------------------+------------------------+---------------------+
```